# git diff: ignore comments

Tags: zsh, git, diff

When using `git diff`, how can I ignore changes which start with `#` ?
For normal `diff` command, I would use something like:

```
diff <(grep -v '^#' file1) <(grep -v '^#' file2)
```

But none of the suggested solutions below work!

Is there really no way to see `git diff` with comments omitted?

## UPDATE:

I tries this in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[pager]
    cdiff = diff-highlight

[alias] 
    cdiff = "diff -w --ignore-blank-lines -I'^#'"
```

When I do `git cdiff`, I get this error:

```
error: invalid option: -I^#
```

## UPDATE2:

this is so frustrating. The syntax `git diff -G'^[^#]'` does not work reliably. Example:

```
$ cat 1.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
jjj
```

initialize new git repo:

```
$ git init && git add . && git commit -m "initial commit" -a
```

add only comment on top of file:

```
$ cat 1.txt
# comment
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
jjj
```

so far, it works as expected. `git diff -G'^[^#]'` does not show the comment as change. But if I add a real change at the last line, and then do `git diff -G'^[^#]'` again, it then shows the added last line (as it should), but also the first line comment which it did not show before.

So basically, as soon as I add any non-comment change, git shows everything, even comments.

Comment: How about a git diff with a regex and adding an alias ‘cdiff’ to that command on your git config?

Comment: @bretonics - that sounds good. Can you explain how to set this up?

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used diff-highlight so I just tried your pager configuration...it works on my end and I don't get your non-escaped colors. Do you happen to have any 3/4 bit color output configurations somewhere in your shell? I've experienced before that escaping them differently can cause issues and previously noticed that similar output when I as using color output configs like `[[0;0m` instead of `"\033[0m"`

Comment: @400theCat, and if replace `-I'^#'` with `-G'^[^#]`' ?

Comment: @nezabudka - now it does not give an error, but is does not filter out comments. Basically no difference to normal `diff`.

Comment: @400theCat, it works like this, if the differences are only in comments, in empty lines and blanks, then the output will be empty. Otherwise, all changes will be visible including blank lines and comments.!

Comment: @nezabudka - but that is not what happens. It behaves identical as normal diff, ie it does show the comments.

Comment: @nezabudka - I have explained everything at length, with example in my UPDATE3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s possible to do this by filtering all files before `diff`ing them.

First, write a small helper, and call it `stripcomments` (executable, somewhere on your `PATH`):

```
#!/bin/sh -
exec grep -ve '^#' -- "$@"
```

Then configure a `git diff` mode using this helper:

```
git config diff.nocomments.textconv stripcomments
```

(this will configure the current repository).

Finally, set git attributes to have this helper used on all files:

```
echo '* diff=nocomments' >> .gitattributes
```

(in the top directory of your repository).

`git diff` will now ignore any lines starting with `#`. Note that this will affect line numbering.

If you want this as an alias, rather than overriding all uses of `git diff`, skip the `git config` command above and create your alias as follows:

```
git config alias.cdiff '-c diff.nocomments.textconv=stripcomments diff'
```

Now `git cdiff` will run `git diff` with `#` comments stripped out.

You can configure all this globally, rather than for each repository, by using `git config --global` and storing attributes in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes` (`~/.config/git/attributes`) instead of `.gitattributes`.

See [`man gitattributes`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and [`man git-config`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'd like to do a [git diff with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527215/how-to-make-git-diff-ignore-comments/35301258) and adding an alias `cdiff` to that command on your git config.

```
git diff -w -G'^[^#]'
```

Then adding an alias to your `~/.gitconfig` for this command

```
[alias]
    cdiff = "diff -w -G'^[^#]'"
```

Not sure if that works to your intended purposes, so adjust as needed.

Comment: thank you, but the regex does not work for me. I think it does not match, because I am using `diff-highlight` coloriser. I will update my original post.

Comment: `diff -I'^#'` and `diff -G'^[^#]` - All this will only work if the differences are only in the comments.

Comment: `cdiff = "diff -w --ignore-blank-lines -I'^#'"`

Comment: try rebuilding the config like this: `[alias] cdiff = "diff -w --ignore-blank-lines -I'^#'" ` and replace `[pager] diff = diff-highlight` with `[pager] cdiff = diff-highlight`

Comment: @nezabudka - this does not work. I get `error: invalid option: -I^#`. See my `UPDATE2`.

Comment: @bretonics - please see my UPDATE3.

Comment: @400theCat, looks like this is just git and the fact that if another change is observed in the file where a regex pattern is ignored, it will still show that file's diff. This I did not expect. Not sure if a bug or a feature of ignoring files with matching regex instead of diffs themselves. Sorry, wish I had more to help with.

Answer (score 1):

All through an example:

```bsh
mkdir cdiff && cd cdiff
git init
cat text.txt
# first comment
1
2
# midle comment
3

4
# last comment
git add test.txt
git commit -m 'first'
```

Now let's change it in the working directory:

```bsh
cat test.txt
1

2
# first comment
# last comment
4
bye
```

Create a utility:

```bsh
cat /usr/local/bin/git-cdiff
#!/bin/sh
diff --color -u <(grep -Ev '^(#|$)' $1) <(git show $2:$1 | grep -Ev '^(#|$)')
```

```bsh
chmod 555 /usr/local/bin/git-cdiff
```

Compare the same file from a specific commit with one in working directory:

```bsh
git cdiff test.txt HEAD
```

Or:

```bsh
git cdiff test.txt <hash commit>
```

```bsh
git cdiff test.txt a4ec1
--- /dev/fd/63  2021-07-09 08:09:48.581153921 +0300
+++ /dev/fd/62  2021-07-09 08:09:48.581153921 +0300
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 1
 2
+3
 4
-bye
```